# iOS Why is programmatically created UIButton lacking the transition animation

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I noticed that when I create a `UIButton` programatically it lacks any animation when transitioning from `.normal` to `.highlighted` state, whereas a `UIButton` added through Storyboard has that kind of animation. Is there any `UIButton` property that enables this behaviour?

Please see the comparision below, first is my `UIButton` created with code and second is via Storyboard:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it animate it must be of type `.system` , this will animate

```
    let button = UIButton.init(type: .system)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 200, height: 60)
    button.setTitle("Email", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .green
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
```